# downloading text file in postman but not in browser using restapi in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-href

`$scope.newFile` is my response from backend. Actually my response should be a text file, which is working in postman.But in browser , I am getting

> Cannot GET 
>   /Organizer/%7B%22data%22:%22id/tname/temail/tphone/twebsite/tvenue/ttags/n83/tAny%20Name/ta@b.com/t9009009009/thttp://www.anyname.com/tHall%20A/ttag1,%20tag2,%20tag3/nsunitha/tsunitha@gmail.com/t55555541/thttp://www.sunitha.com/nSuhasini/tsuha@gmail.com/t955555544/thttp://www.suha.com/nRaichel/traichel@gmail.com/t955548458/thttp://www.raichel.com/n%22,%22status%22:200,%22config%22:%7B%22method%22:%22GET%22,%22transformRequest%22:[null],%22transformResponse%22:[null],%22jsonpCallbackParam%22:%22callback%22,%22headers%22:%7B%22Authorization%22:%22Token%2013946cc6c575d61b042b01b6905f1d239b3d9b08%22,%22Accept%22:%22application/json,%20text/plain,%20*/*%22%7D,%22url%22:%22http://http://localhost/1290//entity/campaigns/download_exhibitors/%22%7D,%22statusText%22:%22OK%22,%22xhrStatus%22:%22complete%22%7D

Service.js

```
var url =' http://localhost/1290/';

function downloadExhibitor() {

        var token = 129821sahh;
        var auth = "Token" + ' ' + token;

        var config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
                'Authorization': auth
            }
        }

        return $http.get(url + 'entity/campaigns/download_exhibitors/', config)
               .then(successHandler, errorHandler);
}

function successHandler(response){
    /* we've got file's data from server */
    return response.data;
}

function errorHandler(error){
    /* we've got error response from server */
    throw new Error('ERROR ' + error);
}
```

and eventually the service invocation

JS:

```
$scope.newFile = "";
service.downloadExhibitor()
       .then(function(data){
                $scope.newFile = data;
             }, function(error){ 
                console.log(error);
             });
```

HTML:

```
    <button class="btn" ng-click="downloadAllExhibitors();">
<a ng-href="{{newFile}}" target="_blank">Download</a></button>
```

Comment: Why do you get with  `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` should it be `'Content-Type': 'text/plain'`?

Comment: I tried that too

Comment: Have you check the restapi logs and the developer console in your browser for the http response code etc.?

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code in controller...

```
var file = new Blob([data], {
    type : 'text/plain'
});
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1
        || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file);
} else {
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
}
```

Comment: its opening as blob:http://127.0.0.1:50152/8830652a-9dbd-426e-bcab-4385f3512b6e with datas displaying in table , but not downloading text file.

Comment: thanks Akshaya, it worked in otherway.Between your answer was usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Following code in controller made my work simple , and it downloaded the file finally.

```
            var file = new Blob([data], {
                    type: 'text/plain'
                });
                if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 ||
                    navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0) {
                    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file);
                } else {
                    var a = window.document.createElement("a");
                    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file, {
                        type: "text/plain"
                    });
                    a.download = "filename.csv";
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click(); 
                    document.body.removeChild(a);
                }
```